# How to fetch data and filter the data with another collection in fireStore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have Collection `Diary` and `Users` in FireStore and I work with `Flutter`.

I need to filter `Diary` documents that user's region is **certain region** as matching with `Users`.

For this I write below code:

```
Future<List<DiaryCardModel?>> regionIntializeFetchDiaryGroupUI() async {
    List<DiaryCardModel?> regionList = [];
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> totalDiaryDocs =
        await _diaryGroupRepo.totalIntializeFetchDiaryGroup(5);
    List<DiaryCardModel> initialList = totalDiaryDocs
        .map((diary) => DiaryCardModel.fromJson(diary.data()))
        .toList();

    String myUserId = ref.read(authRepo).user!.uid;
    UserProfile myUserProfile = ref.read(userProvider).value!;

    for (DiaryCardModel diary in initialList) {
      if (!diary.blockedBy.contains(myUserId) &&
          !myUserProfile.blockedUserList.contains(diary.userId) &&
          diary.secretType == "전체 공개") {
        UserProfile? diaryUserProfile = await ref
            .read(authInfoProvider.notifier)
            .fetchUserInfoUI(diary.userId);

        if (diaryUserProfile!.region == myUserProfile.region &&
            diaryUserProfile.smallRegion == myUserProfile.smallRegion) {
          DiaryCardModel? diaryCardModel = await updateDiaryUserInfo(
            diary.diaryId,
            diary.userId,
            diary.timestamp,
            diary.todayMood,
            diary,
          );
          regionList.add(diaryCardModel);
        }
      }
    }

    return regionList;
  }
```

And If user scroll down ListView with this diary items, after I listen ListView's position with `scrollController`, fetch more diaries with startAfter query.

```
    _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);


  Future<void> _scrollListener() async {
    double maxScrollExtent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScrollPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;

    if (maxScrollExtent - currentScrollPosition <= 200 &&
        !_hasExcutedFetchData) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _hasExcutedFetchData = true;
        });
      }

      List<DiaryCardModel?> offsetDiaryModel = await ref
          .read(diaryGroupProvider.notifier)
          .friendStartAfterFetchDiaryGroupUI(userContactList);
      final removeNullList = offsetDiaryModel.where((e) => e != null).toList();

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          items.addAll(removeNullList);
        });
      }
    } else if (maxScrollExtent - currentScrollPosition > 200 &&
        _hasExcutedFetchData) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _hasExcutedFetchData = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

When I fetch 10 items first I store last Document in ValueNotifier and fetch another 10 items from this last document.

```
  Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>
      totalStartAfterFetchDiaryGroup(int offset) async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> diaryRef = await _firebaseFirestore
          .collection("diary")
          .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
          .startAfter([querySnapValueNotifier.value!["timestamp"]])
          .limit(offset)
          .get();
      querySnapValueNotifier.value = diaryRef.docs.last;
      return diaryRef.docs;
    } catch (e) {
      print("totalStartAfterFetchDiaryGroup -> $e");
    }
    return [];
  }
```

It has some problems.

1. When I filter diary items with qualified region, it can has only 1 items. In that case, ListView cannot have scroll with maxScroll and currentScroll something like that, so I can't not fetch more items as listening scroll action.

In short, scroll position and maxScroll value is dynamic, So I can't specify certain point when I fetch more items in this way.

2. When user scrolls down ListView, since it takes time to fetch items, another items is added too late, it doesn't work smoothly.

If I just fetch all items without limit or offset and filter them from the beginning, it takes too much time to load items first.

FireStore doesn't provide some query to filter collection with another collection, I can't find the best way to implement this purpose..

I really need your idea and help.